# Reload UIButton for changing custom badge

Tags: swift, uibutton

I created one custom `UIButton`with badge, and I set when the badge number is 0, that red circle should be gone.

```
 open class ButtonWithBadge: UIButton {

   open func addBadgeIcon(badgeNumber: Int, color: UIColor) {
      let sizeThatFits = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
      let badgeCount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: sizeThatFits.width - 15, y: -07, width: 18, height: 18))
      badgeCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
      badgeCount.layer.borderWidth = 2
      badgeCount.layer.cornerRadius = badgeCount.bounds.size.height / 2
      badgeCount.textAlignment = .center
      badgeCount.layer.masksToBounds = true
      badgeCount.textColor = .white
      badgeCount.font = badgeCount.font.withSize(9)
      badgeCount.backgroundColor = badgeNumber == 0 ? .clear : color
      badgeCount.text = badgeNumber == 0 ? "" : "\(badgeNumber)"
      addSubview(badgeCount)
   }
```

I call this function to change the badge number. This function works perfectly when the number is getting down, but when I pass 0 to it, it couldn't make `clear` of the background badge and replace its text to `" "`. It only works when you open the page again and then when the badge number is 0, it wont add that badge count view. 
I should somehow, reload the button when its number is 0 to remove that badge view. 
could anyone help me on that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
open class ButtonWithBadge: UIButton {

  open func addBadgeIcon(badgeNumber: Int, color: UIColor) {
  let sizeThatFits = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
  let badgeCount = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: sizeThatFits.width - 15, y: -07, width: 18, height: 18))
  badgeCount.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
  badgeCount.layer.borderWidth = 2
  badgeCount.layer.cornerRadius = badgeCount.bounds.size.height / 2
  badgeCount.textAlignment = .center
  badgeCount.layer.masksToBounds = true
  badgeCount.textColor = .white
  badgeCount.font = badgeCount.font.withSize(9)
  badgeCount.backgroundColor = badgeNumber == 0 ? .clear : color
  badgeCount.text = badgeNumber == 0 ? "" : "\(badgeNumber)"
  if(badgeNumber != 0){
  addSubview(badgeCount)
  }
}
```

Comment: but it will not work if you first pass 3 and then pass 0